# Is there any option to display total story points per epic from the current sprint in Jira dashboard, without using any external add ons

Tags: dashboard, jql, jira-agile, sprint

Can't find any gadgets that sum up story points per epic in the Jira dashboard and my company policy doesn't allow to use external add ons.
Tried pie chart gadget, but it shows % based on story count not story points as in the below image

[image]

Can't find a JQL option to sum up story points per epic from the current sprint

Tried using the filter result gadget in tabular form , it lists story points and epics separately but not grouped by epic

[image]